# How to avoid checking for MySQL connection in every request of Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, asgardcms

I have developed a application which is using Elastic Search for frontend APIs and MySQL for admin backend.

Now the problem is if Laravel fails to connect with MySQL for any reason it starts giving 500 error in APIs as well. Please note that APIs routes are completely different (separate Middlewares and Namespace) from backend routes.

This is the error I am am getting when it fails to connect with MySQL:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection     refused (SQL: select * from `setting__settings` where `name` = core::locales     limit 1) in file /var/www/html/nykaatv_github/vendor/laravel/framework    /src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 664
```

Here i want to mention that I am using asgardCMS.

Did any one faced a similar issue before. And if Laravel checks for MySQL connection of each request by default then what is the way to override it.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't check the connection for every request what will you do when your query fails since there is no mysql connection?

Comment: 'mysql' => ['strict' => false ]
edit this in config in database.php